# How internet connection download/ upload speed should be caluculated to one host

Tags: javascript, algorithm, networking

*This is cross post from software engineering Q/A*

There are couple (a lot of) websites provides internet speed test, I tried to build same, but I'm still not able to get the accurate results.

**Trying**

Created several files on server, let say (1, 8, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)KB.
Then on the client side, I'm downloading each of them.
measuring

- start time to request to the server
- 1st response from server
- time it finishes the downloading

then, internet speed = all transfered size / time taken in seconds.

I checked a couple of other websites which do not download large files / larger data (more than 5Kb), but instead a lot of request are made to the server in parallel,

Also there is something smoothing factor or stabalizing factor, or something which samples the data, and calculates better results.

Here is how speedtest.net implemented, but I'm still not able to understand it properly.

https://support.speedtest.net/hc/en-us/articles/203845400-How-does-the-test-itself-work-How-is-the-result-calculated-

Can someone guide me to understand and point to the right direction to calculate internet speed?

**Edit:** I want to show my users on my web/app how much speed they are getting on it. For this I'm trying to apply a general creteria, similar to speedtest, but instead of taking from multiple servers, just want to try with one server only.

Comment: The throughput will vary, depending on the target site. The Internet is simply the collection of ISPs peering with each other, and they decide with which other ISPs they will peer. Some of the connections between ISPs will be slower or more congested (congestion, and therefore your throughput, will vary over time, even on the same target device). You traffic will pass through several ISPs, and which ones will depend on the target.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to compute parameters to be able to stuff the physical communication channel. The main part is to determine which number of parallel downloads will reach the goal.

A single communication is clearly not sufficient because there exist many overheads during which you can send other packets. In a very rough approximation where to receive messages you need to send a packet from A to B to request some data, and then the data is sent back from B to A, you can clearly request something else while the data is sent back. You can also think of how many data packet can be sent along the link from X to Y? Just like you can have several cars in the same road from B to A. Each car being a packet from a given communication.

Determining the speed of a connection is highly dependent on many factors, and what is obtained is only an approximation.

Comment: so for a better approximation, I should send multiple requests to the server at the same and then calculate basedon how many of them went successfully in the given amount of time?

Comment: can you provide me some exmaple.

Comment: This is not the right place for such thing. Your question is too broad. The link you provided has many sufficient information.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Baptiste Yunès